Is there a distribution of values such that removing values decreases the mean?
I am working with some data in which I find that, as more and more samples are collected, the average value of the samples decreases over time.
Originally I thought that there was just some physical phenomenon occurring that is selecting for samples of a average higher value first, but then I had another thought that the samples could be getting selected randomly and the decrease in the average is statistical phenomenon based on the distribution that samples are taken (and removed) from.
Is there a distribution such that as random samples are removed from the distribution, the expected value of further random samples decreases? The samples are removed from the distribution, so sample measurements are not statistically independent.
I have tried some Monte Carlo simulations with various skew and/or fat-tailed normal and Cauchy distributions, but the mean of the sampled data either remains relatively constant (in the case of the normal distribution) or has arbitrary trends or jumps (in the case of the Cauchy distribution) which makes sense given the statistical properties of those distributions.

If a finite sample $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ share a common finite expectation $\mu=\mathbb{E}(X_1)$, then sample size $n$ does not affect the expectation of the sample average,

irrespective if $X_i$ variables are independent or not, and
irrespective if $X_i$ variables are identically distributed or not, as long as their expectations are equal,

because
$$
\mathbb{E}\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)
=
\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left( X_i \right)
=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \mu.
$$
If you see some trend while removing samples, the following might be possible explanations:

$X_i$ variables themselves have different expectations: In this case, $X_i$ are not identically distributed to a degree that affects their expectation, and the individual expectation depends on $i$.
the selection process has altered the distribution of the kept $X_i$. The expectation of the kept $X_i$ variables is now a conditional expectation, given that they survived selection. This conditional expectation does not need to equal the original expectation $\mu$.
the strong dependency in $X_i$ caused artifacts from your numerical experiments. If one $X_i$ value is very low and autocorrelation is very high, it may take a long time (a large number of later samples) for the law of large numbers to show its effect (i.e., washing out the low value through averaging).

